Thonny won't run Micropython on NUCLEO-F401RE (Mac)
I am trying to use a NUCLEO-F401RE with Thonny and micropython in mac (Sonoma 14.6.1). However, Thonny cannot connect to the NUCLEO-F401RE, and it throws the following error:
Device is busy or does not respond. Your options:

  - wait until it completes current work;
  - use Ctrl+C to interrupt current work;
  - reset the device and try again;
  - check connection properties;
  - make sure the device has suitable MicroPython / CircuitPython / firmware;
  - make sure the device is not in bootloader mode.
Also, it won't appear in the files window.

However, I checked the port configuration in Thoony and the device file appears as an option. Also, the NUCLEO-F401RE appears in the Mac system report under the USB Device tree.
The firmware I installed in the NUCLEO-F401RE is called NUCLEO_F401RE.bin and downloaded it from this GitHub repository: https://github.com/curtywang/stm32_micropython_mbed_bins/releases/tag/v1.19
Since my mac only has USB-C, I've tried using different USB adaptors (both original and third party ones) but non of them work.
PD: I need to do this for a class, and a classmate (who also has a Mac) has the same problem.
